# Undefined method bson_type for model in Rails and MongoId

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I'm having issues with mongoid when adding elements to an embeds_many relation: `undefined method bson_type for #<Discount:0x007f3c599747e8>` thanks in advance.

here is my code:

```
class Discount
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :discountable, polymorphic: true
end

class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :discounts, as: :discountable
  field :client_ids, type: Array
end

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def review
    ...
    current_user.push discounts: like_discount
    current_user.push client_ids: params[:client_id]
    ...
  end
end
```

I have tried with another approach but without success; (works for embeds_many but not for a normal array).

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def review
    ...
    current_user.discounts.push like_discount
    current_user.client_ids.push params[:client_id]
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't quite remember, I went back to ActiveRecord and postgresql, mongoid and moped have A LOT of issues and doesn't follow ActiveModel's spec. I think I solved it with `current_user.create client_ids: params[:client_id]` but as I said I don't remember